# what are the issues with iphone web service?

Tags: iphone, web-services, xcode, sdk

I just started doing some reading (new to xcode/iphone development) into web services and most articles say that apple has really dropped the ball on this ... why is this :S?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because Apple doesn't provide any Web-Service API, it's agnostic on this point and you basically have to hardwire anything with URL Requests.

Fortunately, there are third-party libraries out there like ASIHTTPRequest and RESTKit that can make your life easier when coding an app that needs to talk to a Web Service.